# else if issues java

Tags: java

i have a else if loop, the loop searches through the file extension to see if it matches, if it does not i want it to print out the message, i have tried print and println, but it never prints out the message, any ideas what i am doing wrong, as apart from this the loop is working perfectly fine

```
  if (extension.equals("txt"))
        {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        } else if (extension.equals("jpeg")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
        } else if (extension.equals("png")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
        } else if (extension.equals("gif")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF;
        } else if (extension.equals("pdf")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
        } else if (extension.equals("html")) {
            psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_HTML_HOST;
        } else { 
            System.out.print ("Sorry the printer does no support your file type, sorry") ;
        }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code, the message should only be printed if you have extension other than `txt,jpeg,png,gif,pdf and html`. Make sure that `extension` is not null, maybe there is some exception that is ignored

Comment: Use a debugger to see if it steps into the `else` branch. If it runs that line of code but nothing is printed, the error isn't in the code. (Maybe stdout is redirected into a file.)

Comment: Where is this code running? System.out.print() outputs to the console or, more accurately, to the standard output stream. If your application is running where there is no such stream, it won't output.

Comment: You are a very kind printer though! Aside from that: can you show us the actual value of extension during debugging?

Comment: show us the code for "extension.equals()" method, and how you populate(if it is a string)

Comment: Without further code, I would be concerned by simply using `String#equals`, it would be better to use `String#equalsIgnoreCase` to be safe.  Also, JPEG could also use the extension of `jpg` and HTML could use `htm`

Comment: If you turn it around, too, as `"html".equals(extension)` and assuming extension is a `String`, then a null value of the string pass through without an exception.

Comment: @LeeMeador submitted the comment I wanted to write a few seconds earlier :)  in general - it is recommended to use "somestring".equals(stringParameter) in order to avoind nullPointerException in case the parameter is null

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, it is running server side (jsf) and it outputs to a console, all other print outs work fine, in the debugger it goes through all the else if but nothing puts out on the console, and thanks i shall try turning it around now :) thanks for the helps guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, you can check the following

- `extension` is a `String` i.e. with the default `equals()` implementation
- You provide extension other than `txt,jpeg,png,gif,pdf and html`, so the message can be printed

You will better doing your comparison like blew to avoid possible `NullPointerException` and case sensitive comparisons

```
if("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)){
   //...
 }
```

Finally you can try to print a debug statement **outside** any condition and see if you can see it correctly in the `console`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the case sensitive is a great idea !